# Code for Frida to intercept what are the values of arguments passing through the function when it is called in Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, frida

Suppose there is a function which is as below :

```
public String foo(String str,String str2)
{
//some code here
return str+str2;
}
```

What would be the Frida code(**In JavaScript**) to intercept the function get values of both **str** and **str2**?

Comment: this may help you https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies

Comment: Where is the problem? Just apply the default hooking code for Android Java methods as shown here: https://frida.re/docs/examples/android/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Java.perform(function () {
// ClassName = Name of the class you're targeting. E.g for android os 'android.app.Activity'

var class2overload = Java.use("ClassName")

 class2overload.foo.overload('java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String').implementation =  function (arg1, arg2) {
            console.log("Params: " + arg1 + arg2);
            return this.foo(arg1, arg2);

        }

});
```